# Why is a function inside a component called an infinite number of times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have React component :

```
import { Hotels } from "./Hotels";
import WelcomePage from "./WelcomePage";

import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";

import { firebaseConfig, app, db, auth } from "../firebaseConfig";

import { useState } from "react";

function MainPage() {
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState([]);
  const [authentication, setAuthentication] = useState(false);

  async function fetchHotels() {
    const _hotels = [];
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "reviews"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      _hotels.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log("fetched!");
    setHotels(_hotels);
  }
  function isAuthenticated() {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        const uid = user.uid;
        setAuthentication(true);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        setAuthentication(false);
      }
    });
  }
  isAuthenticated();
  fetchHotels();

  return (
    <main className="content">
      <Hotels hotels={hotels} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

After the application starts, the `fetchHotels` function starts to be called endlessly (this is evidenced by `console.log("fetched!")` ).

Under the same conditions, in other components, other functions are called adequately.

Comment: There **has** to be a good previous question we can point this at. I haven't found one yet though.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fetchHotels` at the top level of your function component, so it's called on **every render**. In `fetchHotels`, you eventually call `setHotels` with a new array, which causes a re-render (since the new array by definition is different from the current one). So when that render happens, it calls `fetchHotels` again, which eventually calls `setHotels` again, which causes...

You need to only call `fetchHotels` at appropriate times. For instance, it looks like you only need to do that when the component first mounts, in which case you'd do it inside a `useEffect` callback with an empty dependency array (so that it is only run on component mount). And since nothing else calls it, you can just do the fetch right there in the callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    (async () => {
        try {
            const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "reviews"));
            if (!cancelled) {
                const hotels = snapshot.map(doc => doc.data());
                setHotels(hotels);
                console.log("fetched!");
            }
        } catch(error) {
            // ...handle/report error
        }
    })();
    return () => {
        // Flag so we don't try to set state when the component has been
        // unmounted. Ideally, if `getDocs` has some way of being cancelled
        // (like `AbortController`/`AbortSignal`), do that instead; using
        // a flag like this doesn't proactively stop the process.
        cancelled = true;
    };
}, []);
```

Note I added error handling; don't let an `async` function throw errors if nothing is going to handle them. Also, I used `map` to more idiomatically build an array (`hotels`) from another array (`snapshot`).

(You have the same basic problem with `isAuthenticated`. The only reason it doesn't cause an infinite loop is that it calls `setAuthentication` with a boolean value, so the second time it does that, it's setting the same value that was already there, which doesn't cause a re-render.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke functions in a component like that. What you need to do is invoke it in useEffect and (optional) give it a parameter that triggers the useEffect function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).